# Elasticsearch is not working "No Alive Nodes in Cluster"

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.1

Elasticsearch is not working "No Alive Nodes in Cluster"

Magento 2.4.1

Elasticsearch : 7.12.0

Elasticsearch : https://cloud.elastic.co/

create deployments in Elasticsearch

Using server : siteground

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In magento 2.4.2 I have performed below commands and it's worked for me

```
systemctl status elasticsearch
systemctl enable elasticsearch
systemctl restart elasticsearch
```

thank you !

Answer (score 0):

After you open your terminal then 
Please Try these command to start and enable elastic search.

```
systemctl start elasticsearch
systemctl enable elasticsearch
systemctl status elasticsearch

bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var pub
bin/magento c:c
bin/magento c:f
```

Then refresh your browser. 
Let me know if you got any issues.

Comment: siteground is not  start elasticsearch

Comment: This may be helpful - https://bobcares.com/blog/elasticsearch-no-alive-nodes-found-in-cluster/